# Difference between "dafür" and "dagegen"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Both seem to have the meaning of "on the other hand", but am not sure whether they can be used interchangeably.

Comment: Please check a dictionary. These words are opposites. If you already checked, [edit] your question to provide context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the given context (in other contexts, both words have another meaning) "dafür" is used to point out a different aspect when comparing something, whereas "dagegen" refers more or less to the same aspect.

Example:

> Vollkornmehl hat wertvolle Inhaltsstoffe, Weißmehl dagegen liefert nur
>   leere Kalorien.

-> You refer to the same aspect of nutrional value.

> Vollkornmehl hat wertvolle Inhaltsstoffe, dafür ist Weißmehl billiger.

-> You point out that Vollkornmehl is good, but also Weißmehl has benefits.

Comment: Which given context are you referring to? The OP did not provide any.

Comment: +1, good answer, decoding the poor question nicely.

Comment: @Björn Friedrich: The context in which both words have a meaning like "on the other hand" ;-)